# Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" with spring-kafka 2.8.x

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

With `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka` up to version `2.7.9`, my Spring-Boot application (consuming/producing Avro from/to Kafka) starts fine, having these environment variables set:

```
  - name: SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_PROPERTIES_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL
    value: "http://avro-schema-registry.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:8081"
  - name: SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_PROPERTIES_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL
    value: "http://avro-schema-registry.core-kafka.svc.cluster.local:8081"
```

But with version `2.8.2` (same with `2.8.1` and `2.8.0`), I get the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.
```

Full error from the logs:

```
2022-01-18 07:15:10,162 [main] ERROR SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
    at com.acme.foo.bar.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:478)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:468)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:129)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.<init>(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.java:211)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.<init>(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.java:58)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.configure(KafkaAvroDeserializer.java:50)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.configure(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:139)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.lambda$keyDeserializerSupplier$5(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:142)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createRawConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:415)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:384)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumerWithAdjustedProperties(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:360)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:327)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:758)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:344)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:430)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:209)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:430)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:331)
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:276)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

I don't see a remark about such a change in the [release notes of `spring-kafka`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/releases). And idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the trick is to simply not provide an explicit version for `spring-kafka` (in my case in the `build.gradle.kts`), but let the Spring dependency management (`id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"`) choose the appropriate one.

`2.7.7` is the version that is then currently chosen automatically (with Spring Boot version `2.5.5`).

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue. And after debugging into the code, I found that there is one change in Spring Kafka 2.8
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/852c447442c9ac3a4eb41e2ddbcfc83ebe8c97da This will cause a reconfiguration of your serializer and deserializer, which won't work for avro ones.

> Starting with version 2.8, if you provide serializers as objects (in the constructor or via the setters), the factory will invoke the `configure()` method to configure them with the configuration properties.

There is also a related discussion in [Spring Kafka serialiser config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72228636/spring-kafka-serialiser-config/72231032?noredirect=1)

Looking at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2274 I think this issue will be fixed by providing an extra option to disable the reconfiguration.

```
public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(Map<String, Object> configs,
            @Nullable Supplier<Deserializer<K>> keyDeserializerSupplier,
            @Nullable Supplier<Deserializer<V>> valueDeserializerSupplier, boolean configureDeserializers) {

        this.configs = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(configs);
        this.configureDeserializers = configureDeserializers;
        this.keyDeserializerSupplier = keyDeserializerSupplier(keyDeserializerSupplier);
        this.valueDeserializerSupplier = valueDeserializerSupplier(valueDeserializerSupplier);
    }
```